# WPF Images appear in the designer but not at run time

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF window containing Buttons with Images
when I set the source of those Images to the Images in another project but in same solution they appear correctly in the designer but at runtime the Images disappear
Here is My XAML code

```
<Button>
  <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/MyOtherProject;component/Images/Image.png" Width="50"/>
</Button>
```

I have tried to change the Source to the following: `/MyOtherProject;component/Images/Image.png`
But still encouter the same problem and the Image appears only in desginer but not in run time

the Images Build Mode is none, and the Copy to output directory is false

Edit: this is a screen shot for the image in the designer : [image: image in designer]

And this is a screen shot for the image in runtime: [image: image in runtime]

Comment: The image should be a resource of the project.

Comment: Why don't you set the copy-to-output to true?

Comment: @jcvegan
I tried to use it as a resource but when I do that the XAML says that there is no such Image in that path

Comment: I made also the copy to output true but still no changes

Comment: You need to ensure in correct run-time environment. What you see is indicator that you didn't. You have to store images in same place accessible at design- and run-time. The easiest is to build them into exe-file as resources, but you can also try to setup folder structure.

Comment: Build Action should be Resource, Copy to Output Directory is not necessary.

Comment: You should check the properties of your image. (Default: Solution Explorer and F4)

Comment: @Sinatr 
So I should set the images as resource?

Comment: Ok i changed the Images build type to resource
but not the Source of the Image is not working anymore, how can I fix that
(Notice that the Images are in another project)

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear. The image file should be located in the MyOtherProject Visual Studio project, in a folder named Images. And its Build Action should be set to Resource.

Comment: @Clemens
yes exactly

Comment: Also make sure that MyOtherProject is the assembly name of the project that contains the image file.

Comment: I have made the images as resource and the code works fine but still face the same problem at runtime